# Number on the board eventually composite

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A positive integer is written on the board. Each second you write 3 or 9 on the right next to it. Is it true that you always get a composite number in finite time?

(One can easily check that the digits 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8 easily give a composite number. That's why I am asking only for 3 and 9.)

If we only allowed 3, then given a prime $p\geq10$, the infinite sequence 3, 33, 333, ... will have two numbers with the same remainder mod $p$ (Pigeonhole principle) and by subtracting and removing 0s we get a number $A$ composed of 3s and divisible by $p$ - in which case $\overline{pA}$ shall be composite.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: To clarify - are we repeating the same digit, or can we mix 3s and 9s? For example, $1\to 13\to 139\to 1393\to 13933\to 139339$.

Comment: @jmerry You can mix.

Comment: Why is it clear that, say, using $1,7$ or $3,7$ can't work?

Comment: @lulu Because when you write 1 you shift the remainder mod 3 by 1, so with at most two 1s (or 1 and 7 or two 7s) you get a multiple of 3.

Comment: Ok...since $1,7$ are both $\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ I can see that case...

Comment: I also don't understand your argument that excludes all $3's$.  It is not true that your sequence always becomes divisible by any specified prime...if $p=11$ and I start with $7$, so your sequence is $7,73,733,7333,\cdots$.  Then none of those terms are divisible by $11$ (they are all $7\pmod {11}$).

Comment: Ok: if $p>5$ is a prime that divides the starting number then, letting $n$ be the order of $10$ $\pmod p$, adjoining $n$ $3's$ gets to a number divisible by $p$.  Thus, in my example, $7333333$ is divisible by $7$ since $10$ has order $6$ $\pmod 7$.  That doesn't work if you start with $2^a$ or such, of course.

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't see any way to attack the $3,9$ case.  Doesn't mean there isn't one, of course.

Comment: @lulu ok, what if we assume that the starting number is prime?

Comment: sorry, I really don't see a way to attack even special cases.  You get too many choices.  Like I say, though, you should clarify your argument regarding all $3's$.  The argument I gave is strong, but it doesn't work for all starting points.

Comment: An infinite sequence of this kind would be a miracle, but I do not see a possibility to rule it out.